# Java Move to new row if all columns filled grid

Tags: java, grid

I am trying to make a list of buttons which are created dynamically. I am arranging them using `GridLayout`. I want that, if the buttons number exceeds a particular number like 12, then the row must change i.e. in the every row there will be 12 buttons.

```
    String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[DataCount]);

    setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(4, 4));
    for (int i = 0; i < DataCount; i++) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0;
        //c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        if(i > 12)
            c.gridy = 1;

        buttons[i] = new JButton(linesArray[i]);
        buttons[i].setName("iname"+i);
        buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
        jPanel1.add(buttons[i], c);        

        jPanel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,0,1,0,Color.BLACK));

    }
```

How can I achieve the above task ?

Comment: Have you thought of using a `GridLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you know in advance how many buttons you're going to create, since you're looping over `dataCount` variable and creating a new button in each iteration.

Now you're creating your grid layout with the following constructor:

```
new java.awt.GridLayout(rows, cols)
```

And you're creating it 4x4. So when you create it, just check to see how many columns you want to create. for example:

```
int cols = dataCount > 12 ? dataCount / 12 : dataCount / 4;
int rows = (int)Math.ceil(dataCount / cols);

setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(rows, cols));
```

You might want to check the fine tuning of `Math.ceil` to ensure you get enough rows and columns to contain your data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, `dataCount` is dynamic. It get this value by reading the lines of a text file. So, it gets the value according to the number of lines which may vary.

Comment: But do you read the file once or do you constantly read it and it is changing during your program's run? If you only read the value once and then create the grid accordingly, it doesn't matter. And if you read it again, simply change the number of columns and rows using `setRows` and `setColumns` according to the calculation above.

Comment: I read the file once I start the program only. But if I close the program & make any changes in the file's number of lines, then the variable dataCount will change. What `c` constraint should I need to set in the above program ? Do I remove all the `c` constraints ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't think you should be using the constraints for that at all, since when you define the grid you'll define how many rows and columns you want and it'll fill your grid as needed.